# creating a theme in magento2

Tags: magento2

I am new to magento framework, can anyone help me out in creating a child theme in magento2.1.3. I searched a lot and i am finding configurations for older versions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It very simple to create your own theme in 2.1.3

1. Create folder under app/design/frontend/New/Theme
2. Copy 3 files from vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/composer.json,registration.php and theme.xml and put under
   app/design/frontend/New/Theme folder.
3. Open your theme.xml update title to "New Theme" and just after this tag put Magento/blank it will look like 
   New Theme
   Magento/blank
4. Open registration.php and update theme name like

   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
   'frontend/New/Theme',
   **DIR**
   );
5. Now go to admin click content->configuration
   click edit on the third row and select your theme from a dropdown with the name "New Theme" and save.
6. After that clear pub/static files except .htaccess and var/ files except .htaccess.
7. Run this command:  php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

That's All !!!